# Matrix triple product with theano

Tags: python, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, theano, blas

This is pretty much the same question as here [Matrix/Tensor Triple Product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206293/matrix-tensor-triple-product) , but for theano.

So I have three matrices `A`, `B`, `C` of sizes `n*r`, `m*r`, `l*r`, and I want to compute the 3D tensor of shape `(n,m,l)` resulting from the triple (trilinear) product:

```
X[i,j,k] = \sum_a A[i,a] B[j,a] C[k,a]
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are shared variables:

```
A = theano.shared(numpy.random.randn(n,r))
B = theano.shared(numpy.random.randn(m,r))
C = theano.shared(numpy.random.randn(l,r))
```

I'd like to write it with a single theano expression, is there a way to do so?
If there are many, which one is the fastest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
np.einsum('nr,mr,lr->nml', A, B, C)
```

is equivalent to

```
np.dot(A[:, None, :] * B[None, :, :], C.T)
```

which can be implemented in Theano as

```
theano.dot(A[:, None, :] * B[None, :, :], C.T)
```

Comment: Ah! Adding dimensions, should have thought about that, awesome thanks!