# Fast inner product of more than two matrices in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm currently writting code where I need to compute as fast as possible a kind of inner product between three 2-D arrays.

Let's call them a,b,c. They all have the same size (N x M).

I want to compute the following 3-d array, op, of size (N x N x N), such that op[i, j, k] is the sum over m of the a[i, m] b[j, m] c[k, m]

[(click here for the nice Latex formula)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swvgn.gif)

This is basically an extend version of `np.inner` to 3 inputs rather than 2.

In practice, the dimensions I will run into are something like N = 100 and M = 300 000. The matrices are not going to be sparse at all, so op contains about 1 million nonzero values.

So far, I've attempted two methods.
The first one uses broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
M = 300000
a = np.random.randn(N, M)
b = np.random.randn(N, M)
c = np.random.randn(N, M)

def method1(a, b, c):
    a_i = a[:, None, None, :]
    b_j = b[None, :, None, :]
    c_k = c[None, None, :, :]
    return np.sum(a_i * b_j * c_k, axis=3)
```

The problem with this is that it first computes `a_i * b_j * c_k` which is an N x N x N x M array, so in my case it is simply too much to handle.

I've tried another method using `np.einsum`, and it is much faster than the previous method:

```
def method2(a, b, c):
    return np.einsum('im,jm,km', a, b, c)
```

My problem is that it is still too slow. For N = 100 and M = 30 000, it already takes 95 seconds to run on my computer, so taking M to its actual value of 300 000 is impossible.

My question is: do you know any pythonic way to solve my problem (maybe a magic numpy function?), or do I have to resort to things like cython or numba to actually make this computation feasible?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting one and related to [`this other problem`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30206293/3293881).

**Approach #1: For decent size arrays**

Based on the winning approach there at the above mentioned `Q&A`, here's one solution -

```
np.tensordot(a[:,None]*b,c,axes=(2,1))
```

**Explanation :**

1) `a[:,None]*b` : Get a 3D array of shape `(N, N, M)`. So, for the use case, it would be `(100, 100, 30000)`, which might be a bit too much for regular systems, but might just work out given some extra system memory *juice*.

2) `np.tensordot(..)`: Next up, we would sum-reduce that last axis from previous step with tensor-dot against the third array `c` to have a `(100, 100, 100)` shaped output array.

---

**Approach #2: For very large arrays and with b identical to c**

```
out = np.zeros((N, N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(j+1):
            out[i,j,k] = np.einsum('i,i,i->',a[i],b[j],b[k])

r,c = np.triu_indices(N,1)
out[np.arange(N)[:,None], r,c] = out[np.arange(N)[:,None], c,r]
```

Comment: This is really what I was looking for, thanks!

However, on my computer, this does not seem to run for M = 300 000 (for M = 30 000 this works perfectly :) ).

In my problem, I will also have b = c, do you see any way it can be used to further imrpove the algorithms? This can probably save half the computation time, but I cannot seem to make it properly work in the same fashion as your algorithm.

Comment: @PAb Did you get a chance to try out approach#2 on very large arrays?

Comment: Yes, but this is actually much slower than approach 1. The memory size is no longer a problem, but the python loops are too slow. I aim at N = 100. This means that the loopy approach loops over 100^3/2 values, too much for python to handle. I tried using numba to make the loops faster, which actually works, but this is still much slower than the nice and fast built in functions.

Comment: @PAb Yeah the point was to use `app#1` whenever possible and only if running into memory issue use `app#2`. Good to hear about using `numba`.